# remove span tag with a certain color style php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am reading data from a webpage but I need help writing patterns for preg_replace function.

The webpage contains "Without ability, influence, or power" inside of span tags with style color=#767676

I want to be able to output only 'Without ability, influence, or power' without the span tags. Is there any way I can do it based on the style color inside the span tag? Because there are numerous other span tags in the file.

Here is the code I have written:

```
$link="http://www.myWebsite.com";
$inputlink = @file_get_contents($link) or die('Could not access file: $link');
    // To output the span tag that has style=color:#767676
$outputlink = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style="color:#767676"/i', '$1', $inputlink);
    // To remove the span tags
$string = preg_replace("/<span[^>]+\>/i", "", $outputlink);
echo strip_tags($string);//OUTPUT : Without ability, influence, or power
```

I am getting the entire website content as output. I would also really appreciate if you could provide me a link where I can learn about writing patterns.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the page data is `<span style=color:#767676>Without ability, influence, or power</span>` and **NOTHING** else?

Comment: No it's a webpage with numerous other span and div tags. But I cannot think of any other way to extract this particular text: "Without ability, influence, or power", so I was thinking if there was a way to extract it based on its color.

Comment: You used `strip_tags()` and it removes the span and other tags, so what is the reason to use `preg_replace()`?!

Comment: I used the first preg_replace to get only the span tag that has color style=#767676 and remove all other tags (other span tags and div tags with contents between the tags). I wanted to retrieve only this string:"<span style=color:#767676>Without ability, influence, or power</span>". I used the second preg_replace to remove the span tag, but my approach is probably wrong. Is there any other workaround? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<?php

$link = 'http://www.myWebsite.com';
$inputlink = @file_get_contents($link) or die('Could not access file: $link');
```

I assume that the page "`http://www.myWebsite.com`" is like this:

```
<span style="color:#767676">Without ability, influence, or power</span> <span>if you see this part or see last part in gray color, your regexp is wrong!</span>
```

Now let's write some regular expression

```
$pattern = '/<span style="color:#767676">([^<]+)(?<!<\/span>)<\/span>/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

it will output `Without ability, influence, or power` without `<span>` tags.

Comment: I changed the pattern to a shorter form. Now you can remove `(?<!<\/span>)` too from the pattern to make is shorter.